# wxWidgets: wxString encode using wxCSConv wxMBConv

Tags: c++, c, wxwidgets

I want to encode a .html file (wxString) into hex. I tried to achieve this by

```
data = wxString((const char*)html_stuff, wxCSConv(wxFONTENCODING_UTF8), sizeof (html_stuff));
```

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't the code sample you've supplied up there creating a wxString from a string buffer? ...rather than decoding a stream of hex characters into .html ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I was about to ask what he is trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is converting from UTF8 to unicode

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/classwx_string.html#86a2ec232912c97ed44ba34651d98123

UTF8 uses 1 to 3 bytes to encode each character - it is used to send documents in HTML so browsers can display them.  Unicode uses 2 bytes to encode every character - it is used by wxString.

My guess is that what you want to do is convert a unicode wxString to UTF8.  There are lots of different ways to do that.  The 'best' way depends on several things.  The simplest would be to use wxString::mb_str()   http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.9/wx_wxstring.html#wxstringmbstr

I recomend that you learn something about character encoding.  [Here is a link to my take on it.](http://ravenspoint.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/world-wide-characters/)